# Dual Monitor will not apply

Tags: multiple-monitors

I will apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge.  I have recently installed ubuntu 18.04.  I am unable to apply any kind of dual monitor set up.  I go to devices on my Dell Inspirion.  The laptop recognizes my TV which is a Vizio 32" 1080p Led. When I click the apply button the screen darkens for 15 seconds or so and then reverts back to normal advising me that it is still in single screen mode.  Why is this happening? What can I do to fix it?  I previously had windows 7 and it worked just fine I didn't even need to change any settings.  Please help! Thank you in advance for your time.  Intel® Core™ i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4 Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check for pending updates? 
Also after checking for updates post installation restart and check for additional drivers.

You can do that in **"Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers"**.
I prefer latest **proprietary**,**tested**.

Disconnect all external monitors and TV's.
After install reboot to be sure that the driver and driver version works on your system.
Then you can connect the external display. Sometimes you can have problems on boot, but with monitor to work when you disconnect and connect the display cable.

Comment: I have installed all updates and rebooted.  The TV is still recognized but when I click apply it doesn't take.  My cursor will go to the far right like the other monitor is working but nothing appears on the TV and after about 15 seconds it reverts to single display.  I have checked and replaced all cables. And it has worked before on earlier versions of Ubuntu and Windows.  I don't know how to check if the driver is working on the system.